# Java Inheritance and Generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have some classes that look like this:

**MODEL**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<O extends Object> { ... }

public class Person extends BaseEntity<Person> { ... }
```

**COMMAND**

```
public abstract class BaseCommand<BE extends BaseEntity<BE>> { ... }

public class PersonCommand extends BaseCommand<Person> { ... }
```

**SERVICE**

```
public interface BaseService<BE extends BaseEntity<BE>> {
    public BE create(BaseCommand<BE> command);
}

public interface PersonService extends BaseService<Person> { ... }
```

**SERVICE IMPL**

```
public abstract class BaseServiceImpl<BE extends BaseEntity<BE>> implements BaseService<BE> { }

public class PersonServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<Person> implements PersonService {
    public Person create(PersonCommand personCommand) { ... }
}
```

The `PersonServiceImpl` class won't compile. It's not recognizing that the `create()` method is implementing the `create()` method from the `BaseService` interface. Can anyone tell why `PersonCommand` isn't being recognized as a `BaseCommand<BE>` (in the parameter list)?

Comment: I don't understand why you're parametrizing the class with itself... public class Person extends BaseEntity<Person> { ... }

Comment: they don't have the same return type maybe?

Comment: Basically I do it so that methods in BaseEntity can refer to the type. public BE method(); etc

Comment: The return type is correct. When I use Eclipse to override/implement, it uses Person as the return and it works correctly. It won't accept PersonCommand instead of BaseCommand<Person>.

Comment: @Rachel: Correct, it _shouldn't_ accept a `PersonCommand` instead of `BaseCommand<Person>`. (See my answer for more details. :-))

Comment: this has nothing to do with generics really

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When overriding, method parameters are not covariant (that is, subclasses have to accept a type that the superclass also accepts, not anything narrower).

This is because people can use your `PersonServiceImpl` via the `PersonService` interface, which will accept an argument of type `BaseCommand<Person>` that is not necessarily a `PersonCommand` (imagine if you created a second class that extended `BaseCommand<Person>`).

If you make your method take a parameter of type `BaseCommand<Person>`, your code should compile correctly.

Comment: Makes sense. The BaseServiceImpl class is forcing you to accept all BaseCommand<Person> objects. Thanks for the help. +1 for a good explanation and example.

Comment: Won't let me accept for 4 minutes apparently, but I will. Thanks again.